# How can I create a 3D-grid in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, 3ds

I have been trying to develop a 3D data-visualization software, and now I need to find a way of quickly generating 3D grids in 3DS Max to use like a 3d-chart reference scale-map. I am new to 3DS but it is what I use to generate the objects I work with on the engine.

Is there any simple way of generating such "cage"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3ds Max has "grid" helper objects that should serve your purpose.

See "Autodesk 3ds Max Help > Precision and Drawing Aids > Helpers  > Standard Helper Objects > Grid Helper" in the user help.

Programmatically you can create and manipulate grid helper objects using MAXScript with the "grid" command. Search the MAXScript help for "grid".

Comment: I can't believe that helper has been there for all of this time. Thanks.

Comment: And I can't believe that there are 3dsmax tagged questions here at StackOverflow.com. I only just learned it! :-)